# Handling UI in microservices

Tags: microservices

I am in the process of learning about microservices and there's one thing that I can't seem to figure out and I can't find any resources that give me a direct answer to this. The question is:

Do microservices involve only business logic and database interactions
or do they involve UI components like JS, CSS, HTML as well ?

Comment: Research composite UI technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a notion of what tiers are included in a microservice itself, however generally speaking, when referring to microservices most of the time you're referring to some back end based app.  That begin said - there are companies out there - two that I've talked to directly that are building "microapps" - basically the backend service, facade and a portlet like interface that can be plugged into a federated portal through a layer of orchestration.

For the Java folks - think fully encapsulated JSR-268 like components that are run as independent processes running within a portal itself.

Comment: "...when referring to microservices most of the time you're referring to some back end based app...", I don't think this is a valid statement. It might be truer in the context of monolith applications.

Comment: correction - back end, not back end based app. And key word there is "most of the time"? if you were introduced to microservices especially within the context of Fowler's introduction and other practical implementations via an api gateway - your context would originate with the back end portion of an app

Comment: So would you say that a microservice with a UI is more like a micro app than a micro service by definition?

Comment: Generally speaking yes - you'll hear things like a web application - "backed"by micro services or "I'm developing my application on top of a micro services based architecture and platform".  "MicroApp" is something I've heard only two occasions 1. working with a very large DCO provider, 2. one of the most if not the most successful note taking application (web+ mobile). It's definitely not as popular and the paradigm is very specific to a use case where they want these wholly silo'ed components working in some unified interface.

Answer (score 0):

A microservice can be a complete application including its own UI, business logic and data.